# Append api data to Amazon AWS SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, json, amazon-web-services

I'd love to be able to import/append json api data straight in to a SQL Server database running on Amazon AWS so that I can analyse it. The data source I want to import, on an hourly basis is:

```
https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/
```

I have the SQL Server database up and running on Amazon. This is unfortunately where my knowledge hits a brick wall. I'm an analyst not a dev and I'm really not sure what I should be searching for or studying to help move that data in to the database.

Can anyone advise what would be the easiest way to extract and load this data? I get that the data might need transforming a bit too.

In terms of requirements; I would need everything to run from the Amazon instance - my own PC won't be on 24/7 so would have time gaps if run hourly. I should be fine with building a trigger if that's needed.

If this is not something that is too easy to explain then any sort of brief pointers would be appreciated such that I can more easily explain what I want on a freelance website for someone to sort it for me

Thanks!

Comment: Is the SQL Server hosted on AWS RDS or on a EC2 instance?

Comment: its on AWS RDS.

Comment: I could switch to an EC2 instance if that makes the above easier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it

**AWS console**

- Create a AWS Lambda function - It is a way to run code on demand
  without having a server running all day (cheaper!).
- Use Python, JavaScript(NodeJS), Java or C# to write your Lambda function code.
- You can assign [a trigger](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invoking-lambda-function.html#supported-event-source-scheduled-events) to your lambda function to run each hour.

**AWS Lambda function logic**

- Establish a connection to the database using a connector library for the type of database you are using and the programming language picked.
- Send a request to the endpoint of interest to get your data.
- Do any data transformations needed.
- Then save it to the database using SQL.